# replace Lock screen with Switch Account screen

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos

User successfully logs in as `user@EXAMPLE.COM` .
User is then mapped to `user@ad.example.com` via
`altSecurityIdentities: Kerberos:user@EXAMPLE.COM`

When the user locks the screen, the lock screen is for `user@ad.example.com`, which the user does not have the (randomized) password for.
It is possible for the user return to their session by backing out to the main login screen, which where `EXAMPLE.COM` is the default domain/realm, and logging in there.

Is there a way to force `user@EXAMPLE.COM` as lock screen user or, failing that, cause the lock screen to go immediately to the switch user screen.

I am primarily interested in Windows 7 and 8, but knowledge for other version would also be useful.

Comment: More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the lock screen be the effective equivalent of the switch user screen enable group policy (Functional Level 2012*):

`Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Windows Settings \ Security Settings \ Local Policies \ Security Options -> Interactive Login: Display user information when session is locked -> Do not display user Information`

*This policy is not new in 2012 and shows up in much the same path in lower function levels.